# SQLite databse closing issue while dealing with fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

In tablet application, left handside fragment has listview with cursor adapter   and Right hand side is replacing with fragments. In a process, I am closing database object in Righthand side fragment.  Left hand fragment side also closed.

If i am not closed the database object. Its automactically closing after some time.

So, can you please tell how to deal with database objects while dealing fragments.

Comment: It should not close automatically after some time. What is the behaviour you are observing?

Comment: I am getting exception like "database already closed exception". and while browsing i got to know, If we are not the close database, Its Sqlite taking care of closing connection.

Comment: Are you sure you are not closing the database anywhere? It wil not be closed unless the process is killed

Comment: FYI : SQLiteDatabase is closed automatically under some conditions.

http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.com/2011/03/sqlitedatabase-is-closed-automatically.html

getCount() and onMove() methods of Cursor trigger an actual query using SQLiteQuery. After all required data are obtained, SQLiteQuery decrements the reference count of the SQLiteDatabase instance. When the reference count reaches 0, the database is closed.